# The specific statement of Eilenberg swindle

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, representation-theory

Here is [Eilenberg-Mazur Swindle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Mazur_swindle) in wikipedia, it only gives some examples about the use of Eilenberg swindle. Is there a specific statement of Eilenberg swindle?

I want to know the specific statement of Eilenberg swindle for the following question: Let $C$ be a category with infinite direct sum. Suppose $A,B \in obj(C)$ . $L := B \oplus A \oplus B \oplus A \oplus \cdots$, could we have that $A \oplus L \cong L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $L \cong A^{\oplus \mathbb{N}} \oplus B^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$ and $A \oplus A^{\mathbb{N}} \cong A^{\mathbb{N}}$, so $A \oplus L \cong L$.

Comment: Actually, I am more interested in what is Eilenberg swindle. Could you tell me the specific statement of Eilenberg swindle?

Comment: You have found one. But there are also other ones, for example when $\oplus$ is replaced by an infinite tensor product.

Answer (score 1):

Write $L$ as the [copower](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/copower#examples) $I\otimes(B\oplus A)$ where $I$ is a set. In particular, $I$ is an infinite set and satisfies $1+I\cong I$. We have: $$\begin{align}
\mathcal{C}(I\otimes(B\oplus A),-)
& \cong \mathbf{Set}(I,\mathcal{C}(B\oplus A,-)) \\
& \cong \mathbf{Set}(I,\mathcal{C}(B,-)\times\mathcal{C}(A,-)) \\
& \cong \mathbf{Set}(I,\mathcal{C}(B,-))\times\mathbf{Set}(I,\mathcal{C}(A,-)) \\
& \cong \mathbf{Set}(I,\mathcal{C}(B,-))\times\mathbf{Set}(1+I,\mathcal{C}(A,-)) \\
& \cong \mathcal{C}(A,-)\times\mathbf{Set}(I,\mathcal{C}(B,-))\times\mathbf{Set}(I,\mathcal{C}(A,-)) \\
& \cong \mathcal{C}(A,-)\times\mathbf{Set}(I,\mathcal{C}(B,-)\times\mathcal{C}(A,-)) \\
& \cong \mathcal{C}(A,-)\times\mathbf{Set}(I,\mathcal{C}(B\oplus A,-)) \\
& \cong \mathcal{C}(A,-)\times\mathcal{C}(I\otimes(B\oplus A),-) \\
& \cong \mathcal{C}(A\oplus(I\otimes(B\oplus A)),-)
\end{align}$$
by Yoneda, $A\oplus(I\otimes(B\oplus A))\cong I\otimes(B\oplus A)$. You could consider other variations by considering other bijections that hold primarily for infinite sets e.g. $I+I\cong I$ or $I\times I \cong I$.

It's easy to establish $(I+J)\otimes - \cong (I\otimes -)\oplus(J\otimes -)$ using a similar approach to the above, and we have $I\otimes(A\oplus B) \cong (I\otimes A)\oplus(I\otimes B)$ simply because $I\otimes -$ is a left adjoint. From here the above result can be established via: $$\begin{align}
\mathcal{C}(I\otimes(B\oplus A),-)
& \cong \mathcal{C}((I\otimes B)\oplus(I\otimes A),-) \\
& \cong \mathcal{C}((I\otimes B)\oplus((1+I)\otimes A),-) \\
& \cong \mathcal{C}((I\otimes B)\oplus(1\otimes A)\oplus(I\otimes A),-) \\
& \cong \mathcal{C}(A\oplus((I\otimes B)\oplus(I\otimes A)),-) \\
& \cong \mathcal{C}(A\oplus(I\otimes(B\oplus A)), -)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am not familiar with the definition of copower. I think we can use the examples of the link you provide: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/copower#examples to get that $L \cong I \otimes (B \oplus A)$, is that right? Also could we use Eilenberg swindle to get the result $A \oplus L \cong L$?